# How to test IndexedDB 'QuotaExceededError' without filling disk?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I want to make sure my code handles the `QuotaExceededError` with IndexedDB properly, I'd prefer not torturing my SSD to do so.

Is there any way to set a storage limit (like to say 5 MB) in the developer tools or browser settings?

Comment: Chrome is working on it [Issue 945786](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=945786)

Answer (score 12):

In Chrome, you can launch the browser with [--user-data-dir](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md) pointing at a smaller volume, e.g. via `tmpfs`.

Chrome doesn't have devtools support for such testing, but it's on the wish list.

Comment: Good answer. Expanding on this you can check the storage limits for the error being thrown here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/master/storage/browser/quota/quota_settings.cc#68
and use `sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=1G tmpfs /mnt/mytmpfs` for the specific limit you want to test.

Answer (score 7):

As of today you can open **DevTools**, go to the **Application** Panel and check the `Simulate custom storage quota` label and then provide the maximum amount of MB that can be stored by IndexedDB.

[Chrome DevTools Application Panel Screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHYGm.png)

Answer (score 1):

I've used a VM with a small hard drive. That's not ideal obviously, so I hope someone suggests a better answer!

Answer (score 1):

Building on @joshua-bell's answer but adding detail on exactly how to do this in Mac OSX:

1. Copy the `mount-ram.sh` file at https://gist.github.com/koshigoe/822455 (you will probably want the unmount-ram.sh file for later as well)
2. Save that file anywhere you want
3. From the directory where you saved `mount-ram.sh`, run `sh mount-ram.sh mytmpfs 512`
4. `cd /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS` (at least that's where it was on my machine)
5. `./Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir=/PATH/TO/mytmpfs/`, replacing `/PATH/TO/mytmpfs/` with the path the directory you created in step 3.

Now you've got Chrome running, pointed at a file system with only 512MB of storage.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with a 100MB storage limit, just open Chrome in incognito mode.

To see how much storage you have left, try this:

```
navigator.storage.estimate().then(console.log)
```